# Wrap tag around a certain number of elements in grid

Tags: css, vue.js, draggable, tailwind-css, vuedraggable

So currently I have this functionality where I have a Component that uploads images, and it takes up the full width.

But when I click it, the view becomes a grid-view with two columns, where my component now resizes to fill the first row, first column, while the images uploaded will take up the other spaces (so starting from first row, second column -- then second row, first column and so on.

So my problem is now that I want my images to be draggable, which is wrapped around in a draggable tag, but how can I do this but maintain it for just the images?
My code is as follows (I'm using tailwindCSS and Vue btw):

```
<div>
    <draggable v-model="images" v-bind="dragOptions" draggable=".item">
      <transition-group
        :class="
          images.length == 0 ? '' : 'grid sm:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 gap-4'
        "
      >
        <ImageUploader
          @addImage="addImage"
          ref="deleteRef"
          :key="'uploader'"
          :shouldShowLabel="images.length != 0"
          :class="images.length == 0 ? 'mt-4 flex-grow' : 'flex'"
        />
        <div
          v-for="image in images"
          :key="image.url"
          @click="deleteImage(image)"
          :class="'item'"
          class="cursor-pointer p-2 shadow-lg rounded-md "
        >
          <figure class="image overflow-hidden relative cursor-pointer">
            <img
              :src="image.url"
              :width="image.width"
              :height="image.height"
              alt=""
            />
          </figure>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
```

I have some images to illustrate:

Before Upload:
[image]

After Upload:
[image]

So the thing is when I shift my images, my images array will have an undefined element, which I suspect to be from the ImageUploader component. Is there any way I can take it out so it is not draggable (so the images array will not be corrupted?). Right now I'm making my ImageUploader Component not draggable by using a different key, but yeah.

TLDR: I need my view to look like a grid with 2 columns, but i only want my elements after the first one to be wrapped in my vue draggable so they can be dragged except for the first element.

Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean. But to my understanding you don't want your `<ImageUploader/>` component to be draggable?

Try moving it outside of the draggable component. :)

```html
<div>
 <ImageUploader
          @addImage="addImage"
          ref="deleteRef"
          :key="'uploader'"
          :shouldShowLabel="images.length != 0"
          :class="images.length == 0 ? 'mt-4 flex-grow' : 'flex'"
        />
    <draggable v-model="images" v-bind="dragOptions" draggable=".item">
      <transition-group
        :class="
          images.length == 0 ? '' : 'grid sm:grid-cols-4 grid-cols-2 gap-4'
        "
      >
        <div
          v-for="image in images"
          :key="image.url"
          @click="deleteImage(image)"
          :class="'item'"
          class="cursor-pointer p-2 shadow-lg rounded-md "
        >
          <figure class="image overflow-hidden relative cursor-pointer">
            <img
              :src="image.url"
              :width="image.width"
              :height="image.height"
              alt=""
            />
          </figure>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable>
  </div>
```